# jQuery append preformatted concatenated string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
for (i = 0; i < json.people[NPC_id].dialogs.start.options.length; i++) {
    concat += "\n "+ optionNumbers + ") " + json.people[NPC_id].dialogs.start.options[i].text;
    optionNumbers++;    
}
//append JSON dialog to label...
options = concat;
```

Here I update the HUD:

```
function updateHUD() {      
    console.log(options);
    $('#options').html(options);        
}
```

Then update the HTML:

```
<div id="bottomDisplay">
    <ul>
        <li><b>Options:</b> <div id="options"></div>    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Console.log gives formatted `concat` string...

```
1) What is wrong with it?
2) What is a 狗?
3) Sorry, I don't have time :/
```

But the html comes out in the div id unformatted as:

```
1) What is wrong with it? 2) What is a 狗? 3) Sorry, I don't have time :/
```

Why is that?

Comment: Why don't you simply use a `<ol>` instead of trying to utilize whitespaces?

Comment: @Bergi Oops, you're right... got hung up on the minutia... changed it to `concat += "<li>" + json.people[NPC_id].dialogs.start.options[i].text + "</li>";` then `<ol><div id="options"></div><ol>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML doesn't handle multiple spaces or new lines.

You may :

- put the whole in a `<pre>` element (the simplest would be to have `<pre id=options></pre>`)
- replace the `\n` with `<BR>` : `options = options.replace(/\n/g,'<br>')`

Comment: okay the <br> worked. Im guessing that's because the html can't understand javascript operators like "\n". Also, quick question... Each time I update players locations/redraw the screen, I need to update the strings right? Each time the player moves, player distance to sprite is checked... and in that method, the strings are updated... so in console you can see that the strings are constantly being updated with the ticker

Comment: I don't understand your question in comment. If it doesn't fit in comments, you might want to ask a separate question.